# C - Freeing memory allocated with malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I'm programming in C and have a function `insert()` that allocates memory with `malloc()`. This function is called from another function named `SJF()`. The `SJF()` function calls `insert()` multiple times.

I'm wondering where and how I should `free()` this memory. I don't want to free the memory every time so doing so inside the `insert()` function isn't going to work. So would the best thing be to return the allocated memory from the function and then free it that way?

```
void insertJob (struct node **head, int key, int data) {
    struct node * new_node = NULL;
    struct node * last = NULL;

    /*Create the new node*/
    new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to insert element. Out of memory");
        return;
    }

    new_node->key = key;
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->origBurst = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    /*No element in the linked list. So point head to the new node*/
    if( *head == NULL)
    {
        *head = new_node;
        return;
    }

    /*Traverse to the last node*/
    last = *head;
    while(last->next) last = last->next;

    /*Point last node's link (next pointer) to the new node*/
    last->next = new_node;

    return;

}
```

```
void sjf(int count, const int *submit, const int *burst) {


 int response = 0, wait = 0, turnaround = 0;
 struct node nd;
 nd.minJob = 0;

 // Create job index and clock
  int job = 0, clock = 0, i = 0;

  // Loop through all the jobs (SJF)
  while(job<count) {

          // Update clock as necessary
         if(clock < submit[job]) {
                 clock = submit[job];
         }


        // Bubble up the shortest job in the ready queue


        // Prepare the ready Queue
        for(int j = i; j < count; j++) {
                if(submit[j] <= clock) {

                        insertJob(&head, submit[j],burst[j]);
                        i++;
                }
        }

        // Find shortest job from ready queue
         shortestJob(head, &nd);


         // Calculate the next event (job end)
          int nextevent = clock + nd.minData;


          // Calculate statistics
          int myresp = clock - nd.minJob;
          int myta = nextevent - nd.minJob;
          int mywait = myta - nd.minData;
          response += myresp;
          turnaround += myta;
          wait += mywait;

          // Set clock to the next event time
          clock = nextevent;

          // Increment job
          job++;

          // Loop back to top

        removeJob(nd.minJob, nd.minData);
  }

  printf("Shortest Job First Scheduler\n");
  printf("Resp: %.2f, Wait: %.2f, T/A: %.2f\n", (float) response / count,
                                                (float) wait / count,
                                                (float) turnaround / count);


 //possibly free() memory here
}
```

This code is just a snippet.

Comment: Only `free` memory when you're no longer using it.

Comment: If you're not sure what to do, a tool like [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org) will be there to nudge slash bludgeon you in the right direction.

Comment: @dbush I know that I need to free it at the very end, so that is why I'm wondering the best way to do so. Because i allocate the memory in insertJob() and then would want to deallocate it from SJF() at the very end. But the pointer with the allocated memory would be out of scope at this point.

Comment: @texasRanger009 You *don't* want to free in `sfj` because you just inserted at item into the list at that point.  The item is available via `head` so it is still in use.  You would deallocate the memory if you remove the node from the list.

Comment: @dbush I just updated my SJF() code to the full code snip. It will show that I'm inserting and removing from SJF(). At the end of SJF() i will have removed all items, so i would be good to free() the memory.

Comment: You didn't  show `removeJob`, but you probably want to `free` there.

Comment: @dbush I can show the removeJob(), but that brings up the same question for. Since the memory is allocated in insertJob if i called free in removeJob then it would be out of scope in removeJob. So how would i get access to the pointer to be able to free it?

Comment: It's not out of scope.  It's accessible via `head`.

Comment: If you are done with the linked list when you get to `//possibly free() memory here`, that's a fine place to do it. Otherwise, you must ensure you have a valid `head` pointer to the list when you get to another point you want to free it.

Comment: @David C. Rankin    So when i call free(head) both in removeJob and at the end of SJF , then i run valgrind and it still shows that i have memory leaks. Thats all i wold have to do is free(head) even though the allocated memory are done with the new_node pointer?

Comment: When dealing with a linked list, just as you iterated when you add nodes, you must iterate over all nodes and free each. I doesn't matter where you do it, so long as you do it before the `head` pointer goes out of scope. Your free function can be `void free_list (struct node *n) { while (n) { struct *node victim = n; n = n->next; free (victim); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can clear your whole linked list after you are done using it, I suppose right before your printf call. You have to free the whole nodes of your list and not just head, which means you have to iterate over it, keep the address of the next node in a temporary variable and free the current node before assigning back the next node stored in tmp to the current ptr:

```c
// [...] previous code

struct node *tmp;
struct node *ptr = *head;
while (ptr) {
    tmp = ptr->next
    (void)ptr;
    free(ptr);
    ptr = tmp;
}

printf("Shortest Job First Scheduler\n");
  printf("Resp: %.2f, Wait: %.2f, T/A: %.2f\n", (float) response / count,
                                                (float) wait / count,
                                                (float) turnaround / count);
```

*NB: You can call a function that you call "free_whole_list()", it might be even better as you can reuse for other projects.*

Comment: I'm still having memory leaks with this for some reason